# Why my code can not run CristalReport correctly in C#?

Tags: crystal-reports

I am very new in C# and I develop small code to run my Crystal report but it hangs the machine, I am using VS 2010 with access 2007 and Crystal report 10 and Crystl32.OCX.

My code is:

```
private void Form12_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ConnectionInfo crConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
        crConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = Application.ExecutablePath + "\\Pharma.accdb";
        crConnectionInfo.UserID = "";
        crConnectionInfo.Password = "";
        cr1.LogOnInfo.Equals(crConnectionInfo); //("sa", "password", @"MS Access           Database", "pharma");

        ReportDocument reportDocument = new ReportDocument();



        ParameterFields paramFields = new ParameterFields();

        ParameterField paramField = new ParameterField();
        ParameterDiscreteValue paramDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
        paramField.Name = "CName";
        paramDiscreteValue.Value = "AHmed";
        paramField.CurrentValues.Add(paramDiscreteValue);
        paramFields.Add(paramField);


        this.cr1.RefreshReport();
        this.cr1.Show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the only problem but this line can't be correct:

```
cr1.LogOnInfo.Equals(crConnectionInfo);
```

You are comparing for equality here...

I would rather try:

```
cr1.LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo;
```

which tries to assign/set the ConnectionInfo on the LogOnInfo object.